# Ruby storing data for queries

Tags: ruby, performance, parsing, lookup

I have a string

```
"4813243948,1234433948,1.3,Type2
 1234433948,4813243948,1.3,Type1
 1234433948,6345635414,1.3,Type1
 4813243948,2435677524,1.3,Type2
 4813243948,5245654367,1.3,Type2
 2345243524,6754846756,1.3,Type1
 1234512345,2345124354,1.3,Type1
 1342534332,4565346546,1.3,Type1"
```

This is telephone outbound call data where each new line represents a new phone call. 
(Call From, Call To, Duration, Line Type)
I want to save this data in a way that allows me to query a specific number and get a string output of the number, its type, its total minutes used, and all the calls that it made (outbound calls). I just want to do this in a single ruby file.

Thus typing in this

```
4813243948
```

Returns

```
4813243948, Type 2, 3.9 Minutes total
 1234433948, 1.3
 2435677524, 1.3
 5245654367, 1.3
```

I am wondering if I should try to store values in arrays, or create a custom class and make each number an object of a class then append the calls to each number.. not sure how to do the class method. Having a different array for each number seems like it would get cluttered as there are thousands of numbers and millions of calls. Of course, the provided input string is a very small portion of the real source.

Comment: You can put all the records into one sorted array and whenever you want to search in this array, you can use binary search algorithm to search the number quickly. For the question, holding the entries as arrays or objects; array in ruby is already object, the size of the objects you will create may vary depending on your needs but actually you can check the size of it with `require 'objspace'; ObjectSpace.memsize_of(object)`. I recommend you to implement both versions and check the memory usage on your own. Also you may consider using hash(dictionary) to avoid the complexity of binary search.

Comment: This use-case is where databases shine. If you don't want to install a DB server (mysql/pg, etc.), then at least use an embedded sqlite. Why reinvent a 50 years old technology?

Comment: @FooBarZoo: finding multiple entries with binary search is unnecessarily involved. What they need is a B-Tree or similar.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, in that case you can use another data structure which makes it fast to access to the entry or you can still use sorted array with unique pointers to related set of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a string
>   
>   `"4813243948,1234433948,1.3,Type2
>    1234433948,4813243948,1.3,Type1`

This looks like a CSV. If you slap some headers on top, you can parse it into an array of hashes.

```
str = "4813243948,1234433948,1.3,Type2
1234433948,4813243948,1.3,Type1"

require 'csv'

calls = CSV.parse(str, headers: %w[from to length type], header_converters: :symbol).map(&:to_h) 
# => [{:from=>"4813243948", :to=>"1234433948", :length=>"1.3", :type=>"Type2"}, 
#     {:from=>"1234433948", :to=>"4813243948", :length=>"1.3", :type=>"Type1"}]
```

This is essentially the same as your original string, only it trades some memory for ease of access. You can now "query" this dataset like this:

```
calls.select{ |c| c[:from] == '4813243948' }
```

And then aggregate for presentation however you wish.

Naturally, searching through this array takes linear time, so if you have millions of calls you might want to organize them in a more efficient search structure (like a B-Tree) or move the whole dataset to a real database.

Comment: This did seem to work and isnt too slow.. gives me a mvp without needing a database.. Any way to take the sum of all the lengths after selecting a specific number? Thanks!

Comment: Also how would I move this data into a B-Tree. You dont have to provide code but what would be the steps you would take with this dataset and search objective

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to make queries for the number the call originated from, you could store the data in a hash where the keys are the "call from" numbers and the value is an array, or another hash, containing the rest of the data. For example:

```
{ '4813243948': { call_to: 1234433948, duration: 1.3, line_type: 'Type2' }, ... }
```

If the dataset is very large, or you need more complex queries, it might be better to store it in a database and just query it directly.